# How to host 2 webapps on the same server

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost

I'm working on a VPS with Ubuntu and I configured a webapp called Pathfinder, it's a third party app for a game called EVE Online. 
Now I need to add another app to the server but I don't want to mix anything

I can access pathfinder just fine. But I want to access the other app by using a url similar to this `my.domain.com/otherapp` , the other app is in the `DocumentRoot`.

```
#PATHFINDER VIRTUAL HOST
<VirtualHost *:80> 
ServerName my.domain.com
ServerAdmin admin@bfc.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/my.domain.com

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =my.domain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Should I add another virtual host file for the new app?

Comment: also include any information e.g. are you using cpanel?  what have you tried?  what results or errors?

Comment: @Steve I'm working on a VPS, everything I try seems like it isn't changing anything, yes I've restarted apache... I have Pathfinder running normally, but I need to add another webapp to that server but I don't know how to work with virtualhosts

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: Which server will each of these webapps run under?   If both will run under Apache then your virtual host solution is fine.   If you need a different application server then you will also have to run it on a different port and set up mod_proxy under Apache.